# jQuery html method is removing linebreaks in MSIE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Have tested in Chrome and Firefox, they both preserve line breaks, but MSIE isn't.

Here is proof:

http://jsfiddle.net/rNHAm/

It's a bug of MSIE or jQuery, or it's ok for both? :)

I can't even get third alert in MSIE...

Thanks :)

Comment: You are only showing that line breaks are handled differently in alert boxes.  Is that what you mean?

Comment: Have you tried to launch example in MSIE and Chrome or Firefox? Why line breaks dissapear in MSIE in the example?

Comment: You don't get third alert because the script crashes: `'text(...).html().match(...).length' es nulo o no es un objeto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE appears to remove line breaks from the `.innerHTML` property of the container tag, no matter the format (the `.nodeValue` property of the text node still contains the original value):

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
var t = document.createTextNode("one\ntwo\rthree\r\nfour");
div.appendChild(t);
alert(t.nodeValue);
alert(div.innerHTML);
```

IMHO it looks like an IE bug: in HTML, white space must be collapsed but not completely removed.